# collisions in swift and spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, collision

I'm working with a simple game using `Swift` and `Spritekit` .

**I have 4 nodes in my scene : nodeA1 , nodeA2 , nodeB1 and nodeB2 .**

So **nodeA1 can touch nodeA2** And **nodeB1 can touch nodeB2** .

I want

> nodeA2 touch nodeB2 without nodeA1 touch nodeB1 and nodeB2 and nodeB1
>   is the same.

Is that possible ?

Comment: Do you mean collisions i.e. do you want nodeA1 and nodeA2 to bounce off each other and nodeB1 and nodeB2 to also bounce off each other but for nodes A1 and A2 to go straight through nodes B1 and B2?

Or do you mean contacts i.e. you want to be notified when nodeA1 and nodeA2 touch and also when nodeB1 and nodeB2 touch but you're not interested if either A1 or A2 touch either B1 and B2?

Comment: hey @SteveIves (i mean collisions) , yes node A1 and A2 bounce off each other , node B1 and B2 bounce off each other and and the **important part**  A2 and B2 bounce off each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible, whether or not you mean collisions or contacts

If you can clarify this, I'll tell you how to do it. (I could tell you for both, but that would be extra code.)

EDIT - code here for collisions as described:

1. Define unique categories, ensure your class is a `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` and make yourself the physics contact delegate:

   //Physics categories
   let nodeA1Category:      UInt32 = 1 << 0 // b'00001'
   let nodeA2Category:      UInt32 = 1 << 1 // b'00010'
   let nodeB1Category:      UInt32 = 1 << 2 // b'00100'
   let nodeB2Category:      UInt32 = 1 << 3 // b'01000'

   class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
      physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
2. Assign the categories (usually in `didMove(to view:)` :

   nodeA1.physicsBody.catgeoryBitMask = nodeA1Category
   nodeA2.physicsBody.catgeoryBitMask = nodeA2Category
   nodeB1.physicsBody.catgeoryBitMask = nodeB1Category
   nodeB2.physicsBody.catgeoryBitMask = nodeB2Category

(Make sure you've created physics bodies for each node with the `isDynamic` property set to `true`)

3. Set up collisions:

   nodeA1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = nodeA2Category // A1 collides with A2
   nodeA2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = nodeA1Category // A2 collides with A1

   nodeB1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = nodeB2Category // B1 collides with B2
   nodeB2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = nodeB1Category // B2 collides with B1

   nodeA2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = nodeB2Category // A2 collides with B2
   nodeB2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = nodeA2Category // B2 collides with A2

You should now get all the collisions you want, but no contact notifications. If you want to do something the these nodes collide, you'll have to implement `contactTest` bit masks and also the `didBeg(contact:)` method.